# Помогите разобраться что тут делает цикл for

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
# Hangman Game
#
# The classic game of Hangman.  The computer picks a random word
# and the player wrong to guess it, one letter at a time.  If the player
# can't guess the word in time, the little stick figure gets hanged.

# imports
import random

# constants
HANGMAN = (
"""
 ------
 |    |
 |
 |
 |
 |
 |
 |
 |
----------
""",
"""
 ------
 |    |
 |    O
 |
 |
 |
 |
 |
 |
----------
""",
"""
 ------
 |    |
 |    O
 |   -+-
 | 
 |   
 |   
 |   
 |   
----------
""",
"""
 ------
 |    |
 |    O
 |  /-+-
 |   
 |   
 |   
 |   
 |   
----------
""",
"""
 ------
 |    |
 |    O
 |  /-+-/
 |   
 |   
 |   
 |   
 |   
----------
""",
"""
 ------
 |    |
 |    O
 |  /-+-/
 |    |
 |   
 |   
 |   
 |   
----------
""",
"""
 ------
 |    |
 |    O
 |  /-+-/
 |    |
 |    |
 |   | 
 |   | 
 |   
----------
""",
"""
 ------
 |    |
 |    O
 |  /-+-/
 |    |
 |    |
 |   | |
 |   | |
 |  
----------
""")

MAX_WRONG = len(HANGMAN) - 1
WORDS = ("OVERUSED", "CLAM", "GUAM", "TAFFETA", "PYTHON")

# initialize variables
word = random.choice(WORDS)   # the word to be guessed
so_far = "-" * len(word)      # one dash for each letter in word to be guessed
wrong = 0                     # number of wrong guesses player has made
used = []                     # letters already guessed


print("Welcome to Hangman.  Good luck!")

while wrong < MAX_WRONG and so_far != word:
    print(HANGMAN[wrong])
    print("\nYou've used the following letters:\n", used)
    print("\nSo far, the word is:\n", so_far)

    guess = input("\n\nEnter your guess: ")
    guess = guess.upper()

    while guess in used:
        print("You've already guessed the letter", guess)
        guess = input("Enter your guess: ")
        guess = guess.upper()

    used.append(guess)

    if guess in word:
        print("\nYes!", guess, "is in the word!")

        # create a new so_far to include guess
        new = ""
        for i in range(len(word)):
            if guess == word[i]:
                new += guess
            else:
                new += so_far[i]              
        so_far = new

    else:
        print("\nSorry,", guess, "isn't in the word.")
        wrong += 1

if wrong == MAX_WRONG:
    print(HANGMAN[wrong])
    print("\nYou've been hanged!")
else:
    print("\nYou guessed it!")

print("\nThe word was", word)

input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

Помогите пожалуйста, обьясните суть работы цикла for, распишите на человеческий язык что тут происходит:

```
 used.append(guess)

    if guess in word:
        print("\nYes!", guess, "is in the word!")

        # create a new so_far to include guess
        new = ""
        for i in range(len(word)):
            if guess == word[i]:
                new += guess
            else:
                new += so_far[i]              
        so_far = new
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Изначально

```
so_far = "-" * len(word)
```

по коду, содержит количество символов  `'-'` равное длине слова или количеству букв. А далее цикл

```
new = "" # create a new so_far to include guess / создается переменная "new" для 
                                              взаимодействия с "so_far"
```

for i in range(len(word)):

```
if guess == word[i]:  / по буквам сравнивает, если буква в этом отгадываемом слове
    new += guess      /если есть в место символа '-'вставляем букву и сохраняем в "new"   
else:
    new += so_far[i]  / если нет, допечатываем символы '-' из переменной "so_far"
```

so_far = new

Очень своеобразный момент, идет пересохранение переменной "so_far" через переменную "new", в которой отражено реальное положение угаданных букв и прочерков в данный этап отгадывания слова.

Такое своеобразное нанизывание на ниточку бусенок, в виде отгаданных букв.
И далее следует таким макаром, до полного отгадывание или не отгадывание слова.

Answer (score 0):

Если введённая буква содержится в загаданном слове, то она добавляется в строку `so_far`, в которой записаны уже угаданные ранее буквы.

Comment: Можете разбить весь процесс на части и обьяснить каждую строку? Буду очень благодарен)!

Comment: И еще вопрос почему в so_far буквы попадают по индексу, имею ввиду по порядку, как в word, какая строка за это отвечает?

Comment: @ЭдуардВан все строки за это отвечают, потому что so_far собирается по одному символу.

Comment: ну их тогда по индексу нужно расставлять? разве нет?

Comment: Они и расставляются. Первый добавленный символ - индекс 0, второй символ - индекс 1, итд.

Comment: Да, а в игре они расставляются не по порядку добавления, а по порядку, как в слове, как в поле чудес, ты отгадал букву, и она сразу попадает на все место, где она есть в слове.

Comment: @ЭдуардВан да. Для того и условие if-else

Comment: тут сверху уже есть условие, что если в word есть guess:, а как так получается что может сработать else если эта буква сто процентов есть в слове, так как условие выше просто бы не выполнилось

Comment: Если в word есть guess, то собираем новую строку с учетом guess.